# Running exports on MySQL Workbench not working on vagrant

Tags: mysql, vagrant, mysql-workbench

I am trying to export DBs on mySQLWorkbench but get this error:

> 13:53:12 Dumping regaplus (all tables) Running:
>   /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/mysqldump
>   --defaults-file="/var/folders/gr/m598wr9n623bw270kcf4slfh0000gn/T/tmpWI5fNl/extraparams.cnf"
>   --enable-cleartext-plugin --user=root --host=localhost --protocol=tcp --port=22559 --default-character-set=utf8 --single-transaction=TRUE --skip-triggers "regaplus" mysqldump: unknown option '--enable-cleartext-plugin'
>
> Operation failed with exitcode 2 13:53:13 Export of
>   /Users/monique/dumps/Dump20151011.sql has finished with 1 errors

I am running vagrant and have tried to SSH and look through this option in the following files:

/etc/mysql/my.cnf 
and reviewing: 'mysqladmin variables' AND 'mysqld --verbose --help'.

I cannot find this option anywhere? --enable-cleartext-plugin ?

I am new to vagrant setup and so not sure if this error is related to vagrant or workbench or the integration.

Comment: Is it really so difficult to trigger a simple web search? You would immediately end up at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cleartext-authentication-plugin.html.